# What is "docker-init" in "docker version" output?

Tags: docker, docker-desktop

When I run `docker version`, I will see `docker-init` version in the `Server` part. May I ask what is `docker-init` for? Is it a Linux init system specific to Docker Desktop? I couldn't find any information about it.

Comment: as for reference https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#specify-an-init-process

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It shows what version of [Tini](https://github.com/krallin/tini) is included in the version of Docker you have installed.

The project page tells what it does better than I can.